# Attaching unique identifiers in jQuery to returned SQL data for use in dynamic list

Tags: jquery, html

I have a group of spans that are populated with data from an SQL query.  What I want to have happen is when I click on a span, the corresponding sub-genres appear.  Clicking again hides tit.

The problem is that it's an all or nothing situation.  When I use jQuery to show the sub-genres, ALL the sub-genre lists are shown and NOT the one for the specific span I'm clicking on.

I have tried several different jQuery combinations but I'm unclear as to how to distinguish one group over another, so that I am only showing the sub-genres that correspond to the genre.

Here is the code that generates the genres and the sub-genres.

```
<div id="signUpForm-2">
        <fieldset class="genre_profile">
            <p>Please select the genre(s) of music you write:</p>
            <div id="genres">
                <?php
                    $query = 'SELECT * FROM genres ORDER BY genre DESC';
                    $genres = mysqli_query($db,$query);
                    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($genres) ){
                        // echo out individual spans
                            echo "<span class='genre'>";
                            echo ucfirst($row['genre']);
                            echo "</span>";
                            // collect id from $row
                            $genre_id = $row['id_genre']; // uses id to access sub-genres
                                $query = "SELECT * FROM genres_sub WHERE id_genre = '{$genre_id}'";
                                $sub_genres = mysqli_query($db, $query);
                                while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sub_genres) ){
                                    echo "<span class='hidden sub_genre'>";
                                    echo ucfirst($row['sub_genre']);
                                    echo "</span>";
                                }
                    } // end of Genres loop
                    mysqli_free_result($genres);
                ?>
            </div>
    <!-- input field to hold fields.  input must expand to hold.-->
            <div id="genres_select"></div>
    <!-- hidden input fields to collect selections -->
            <input type="hidden" id="genres" name="genres">
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

I believe the solution lies in targeting a sub_genre id that corresponds to the parent genre but I'm not sure of how to implement this in my jQuery.  The jQuery I have right now is a simple event handler to the genre spans.

```
$("span.genre").click(function(){
    // code goes here..
});
```

I've experimented around with the this keyword, but I am missing some sort of identifier for the corresponding sub-genre.

Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: any chance of adding your jquery?

Comment: show generated html and javascript. No point posting server code for a client side issue. We shouldn't have to mentally compile your php

Comment: The HTML structure could be better. A linear series of spans is not particularly useful.

Answer (score 0):

as you're echo'ing out your genre already put that as an id to show the sub set.
Haven't done anything to try and smarten it up as I'm lying in bed now just going to sleep so it looks a mess, you can sort that out.

```js
$('.genre').hover(function(e){
  
 $('.'+$(this).attr('id')).css('display','inline');
  },
                 function(e){
$('.'+$(this).attr('id')).css('display','none');

});
```

```css
.genre{display:inline-block;}
.hidden{display:none;background-color:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="genre" id="folk">folk</span>
  <span class='hidden folk'>irish</span>
  <span class="hidden folk">latin</span>
<span class="genre" id="blues">blues</span>
  <span class='blues hidden'>south</span>
  <span class="blues hidden">north</span>
```

Comment: Thanks Billy. I'm new to programming so some of this stuff kind of goes over my head.  
For the id's in the spans, are the html bits generated by my PHP? Are these things I'm echoing?

Comment: yes they are generated by php. do something like `echo "<span class='genre' id='".$row['genre']."'>";echo ucfirst($row['genre']);echo "</span>";` then in the sub sections add $row['genre'] echo'ed out as a class